# iNEXT se not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, inext

I am using iNEXT to make a rarefaction curve from abundance data. The ggiNEXT function returns the error "object 'se' not found" even when I put se=FALSE into the function. Help?

```
>out<-iNEXT(Sum3)
>ggiNEXT(out)
Error in fortify.iNEXT(x, type = type) : object 'se' not found
> ggiNEXT(out, se=FALSE)
Error in fortify.iNEXT(x, type = type) : object 'se' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the additional arguments `q=[order of your DF's Hill number], datatype="abundance"` to your first call of iNEXT.

I did so with the generic dataframe in the iNEXT help file ("spider",q=0) to your code and it ran without error.